# How to prevent input field from accepting values grater than max value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

I want to stop taking input if value is greater than max value. if i use keypress event then i can achieve this by returning false if value is greater than max value. but problem is keypress doesnt give latest value. and if i use keyup then return false does not work.

```
 <div><input type="number" allowNumbersOnly value="" (keypress)="keypress($event)" (keyup)="onKey($event)" [(ngModel)]=""/></div>


below code works but does not give latest updated value:

  keypress(event){
    if(event.target.value > 500){
      return false;
    }
  }
```

and this gives latest updated value but return false does not work here:

```
  onKey(event){
    if(event.target.value > 500){
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: try with `onchange` and add a message as value should be greater >500

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent the default behaviour of keyup, it gets fired when user releases the key that mean when the default action has already been performed.

However you can slice the entered last value when user enter value greater than 500.
Like this:

```
keyUp(event) {
    if (event.target.value > 500) {
      let length = event.target.value.length;
      event.target.value = event.target.value.slice(0, length - 1);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

In html:

```
<input type="number" maxlength="3" (keyup)="keyUp($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this like this.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('edit-items'[0].oninput = function () {
       var max = parseInt(this.max);

        if (parseInt(this.value) > max) {
            this.value = max; 
        }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="edit-items" max='10'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In additon to Priyesha's answer, you have to put the  max="500" attribute into input elemnt to prevent the value to be increased via inout up arrow.

```
<input type="number" allowNumbersOnly value="" (keyup)="onKey($event)"  max="500"/>
```